# I am getting a LoadException error here, despite never changing the location of the .fxml file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX project in IntelliJ IDEA. I swear that I have never changed the location of main-db.fxml, and it used to run smoothly before. But now all of a sudden it's giving me a LoadException error, help!

HelloApplication.java:

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {


    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser(); 



    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception, InvalidFormatException {

        fc.setTitle("Select the Excel file");

        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Excel file","*.xlsx"));

        File sheet = fc.showOpenDialog(new Stage());


        String sheetPath = sheet.getPath();


        if (sheet != null) {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("main-db.fxml"));


            **Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load(), 600, 480);**

            stage.setTitle("Welcome");

            stage.setScene(scene);

            stage.show();


            }


        }
    }
```

HelloController.java:

```
public class HelloController {

    @FXML
    public Pane DBPane;

    @FXML
    private Label studentCount;

    @FXML
    private Label testLabel;

    // method to allow access to a label from other classes
    private final String path;
    private File sheet;


    public HelloController(String path) {

        this.path = path;
        this.sheet = new File(path);
    }

    public void showCount() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fisDB = new FileInputStream(sheet);
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fisDB);
        Sheet names = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int count = names.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

        studentCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
```

main-db.fxml (Users\PC\IdeaProjects\IA_real_2\src\main\resources\com\example\IA_real_2\main-db.fxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


**<Pane fx:id="DBPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.ia_real_2.HelloController">**

   <children>

      <Label fx:id="studentCount" layoutX="53.0" layoutY="64.0" text="Count here">

         <font>

            <Font size="41.0" />

         </font></Label>

   </children>

</Pane>
```

IntelliJ flagged the lines that I've boldened as being the root of the cause. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Here's the exception log:

```
Exception in Application start method

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)

    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/PC/IdeaProjects/IA_real_2/target/classes/com/example/ia_real_2/main-db.fxml:7


    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2722)

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:946)

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:983)

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:757)

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2853)

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)

    at com.example.ia_real/com.example.ia_real_2.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:45)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)

    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)

    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)

    ... 1 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.ia_real_2.HelloController.<init>()

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3685)

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2854)

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:941)
    ... 17 more

Exception running application com.example.ia_real_2.HelloApplication
```

I've tried to reformat the path of the fxml file to "/com/example/ia_real_2.fxml" but to no avail. I've also looked around the dependencies but nothing sus has came up either. I've looked at the project structure of a default JavaFX project and it seems to be identical - the only difference being that the default project runs while mine doesn't.

Comment: Can you repost all your code and stack trace, [properly formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), without all the HTML `<br/>` elements added?

Comment: Anyway, why do you think the location of the FXML file is the problem? The stack trace clearly indicates the issue is on line 7 of the FXML (which it couldn't possibly say if it couldn't find the FXML file). It says the issue is that your controller class `HelloController` doesn't have a no-argument constructor.

Comment: Pardon my formatting, and I am still pretty new to JavaFX. When I started up the project, I didn't see a no-argument constructor within HelloController yet it still ran so I assumed it just wasn't required.

Comment: If you don't define any constructor, a default no-arg constructor is defined by default. (This is just base Java, nothing to do with JAvaFX or FXML. A class needs a constructor otherwise instances of it cannot be created.) If you define your own constructor, of any signature, then you don't get the default one for free.

Comment: Just edited my question - added HelloController.java. I did define a constructor that requires a string parameter, so yes instances of it should be able to be created - not in this case apparently..

Comment: You're missing the point. A controller *must have* a no-argument constructor (under default usage). (Just think about it: the controller instance is created by the `FXMLLoader` when you load the FXML. How do you expect the `FXMLLoader` to know what to pass to the constructor if it has a parameter?) By defining a constructor which takes a parameter, you no longer have a no-argument constructor, so the code fails when the `FXMLLoader` tries to load it. You can see this from the stack trace, where `FXMLLoader.processAttribute()` tries to invoke a constructor.

Comment: If you want to know how to provide a parameter to your controller (e.g. how to set the `String path` parameter that your controller requires to operate), see: [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)